# Help with Understanding MoK/Secureboot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, uefi, secure-boot

I'm trying to understand How MoK shim64 works exactly.

What I understand it as is:
Securenboot has a list with Whitelisted Kernerl-hashes belonging to
Windows, Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSuse and others.
Which are signed and approved by Microsft
Ubuntu checks a different Whitelist with(Machine owner Keys) managed by shim64

1 Ubuntu asks SB: am i alowed to run SB: yes

2 Drivers ask Ubuntu : am i alowed to run Ubuntu: yes

If No

3: Ubuntu asks user to enroll MoK whitelist and reboots

4 during reboot user is asked to approve the new MoK

if yes

5 repeat

Question

Does adding MoKs modify the oiginal MS whitelist in NVRAM or is it stored completely seperatly

Do MoKs have to be stored in NVRAM?